# Rails new line on <td>

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out a way I can have a new line in a cell so it is displayed in this format:

```
Phone Number 1
Phone Number 2
Phone Number 3
```

Let me show you the code that I have now so that you may understand my problem:

```
<tbody>
        <% @books.each do |book| %>
  <% record = AddressBookController.address_book(book.id) %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= record['last_name'] %></td>
            <td><%= record['phone_numbers'].join ', ' %></td></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
</tbody>
```

The .join will break up the array and display it like this: `Phone Number 1, Phone Number 2, Phone Number 3`

How can I make it show like first example in this post?

Comment: does record['phone_numbers'] contains multiple phone numbers, and you want to print those numbers below the last name?

Comment: @Rails Guy Yes that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join using `<br />`.  The following should work:

```
<td><%= raw record['phone_numbers'].join('<br />') %></td>
```

Also, use the `raw` helper so that the output isn't escaped.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you.  I did not know about raw.  I tried that without raw and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I guessing you're looking for this:

```
<tbody>
    <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <% record = AddressBookController.address_book(book.id) %>
        <% record['phone_numbers'].each do |number| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= record['last_name'] %></td>
          <td><%= number %></td></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```